# How to clear the output in a cell in itorch notebook?

Tags: lua, output, torch

In itorch notebook, Is there a way to clear the output of a cell with code?
What I would like to do is to dynamically display the progress, like a loading bar.
The reason for this is when a lot of computation is involved, I would like to track how far the progress has gotten, and whether it froze or not.

So basically I would like to print the number of iteration I'm in in percentage form and overwrite it in the next iteration.

Any ideas?

Comment: Anyone has an answer??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the carriage return character (`\r`) to overwrite the same line in a cell.

For example:

`io.write("Hello") -- No newline
io.write("\rWorld")`

just displays

`World`

You can use this to write several times the progress of your process, without adding multiple lines.